# Chart.js data background color is overwriting point background color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm working with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). I have a single data line with a specific color. I want the points of these data line to be in a different color. According to the documentation you can do this with `Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.backgroundColor`

```
 var ctxLine = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext('2d');
 lineChart = new Chart(ctxLine, {
 type: 'line',
 data: {
     labels: dates,
     datasets: [{
           data: ['...'],
           backgroundColor: "rgba(52,152,219,0.4)"
       }]
 },
 options: {
    elements: {
         point: {
              borderColor: "rgb(255,255,0)",
              backgroundColor: "rgb(255,0,0)"
          }
      }                     
   }
});
```

`point.borderColor` is working properly, but `point.backgroundColor` is only working if I remove the the first `backgroundColor` field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself. I wasn't aware that there are different versions of chart.js

I am using v2.0 and there exists a property named `pointBackgroundColor`

```
var ctxLine = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext('2d');
lineChart = new Chart(ctxLine, {
type: 'line',
data: {
     labels: dates,
     datasets: [{
           data: ['...'],
           backgroundColor: "rgba(52,152,219,0.4)",
           pointBackgroundColor: "#fff"
       }]
}
});
```

Comment: works for the points but does not change the backgroundcolor in the legend of this dataset

Comment: For this one need to add this ( backgroundColor={['rgb(230, 0, 0, 0.7)']} ) as property of the canvas. It seems that an RBG of 170,170,170 is defined as default in chart js and is overwriting any previous setting of backgroundcolor. This is only valid for the very first dataset. For any further dataset setting backgroundcolor works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Chart.defaults.global.elements.point.backgroundColor` only takes a single Color string.

I don't believe would be possible to have different colored points. [Here is the documentation page for it.](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-configuration)

I tried to plug in an array into that backgroundColor property but it defaulted to a different color.  [Have a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u447k57/), if you want to play around.

You could always submit a feature request.